# Bootstrap 4 with wordpress jquery

Tags: jquery, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

Bootstrap 4 doesn't work with  wordpress jquery. When I include jquery cdn everything works. How to fix this mistake without connecting own jquery?

[image]

Comment: How do you load bootstrap/ jquery in your wordpress? Please add more information to your question. At the moment it looks like: it doesn't work, here's an image to show. We can't help you if you don't provide enough information

Answer (score 0):

A workaround: Add the following line into a script file that is being loaded after jQuery and before Bootstrap:

```
var $ = window.jQuery
```